# Unable to Communicate with Azure IoTHub from ThreadX client

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, root-certificate, threadx

We are creating an application where ThreadX based client would be communicating with IOT Hub. Made appropriate adapter changes to make client work with IOT Azure C SDK. We observe "Bad Certificate" error thrown by client on wire shark error. From wireshark we are certain that client sends "Hello" on which Server (IOT Hub) responds "Server Hello, Certificate, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done". It is here when client tries authenticate server certificate we see "Bad Certificate" being thrown. We are attaching in mail the root certificate we are adding to client and the wireshark we see stating bad certificate.

[image: Device Error]

Comment: As far as I know the C IoT Hub SDK doesn't support ThreadX at the moment and it's in progress.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about the Azure C SDK support for ThreadX.

If you are certain from Wireshark that the steps till `Server Hello Done` are successfully completed, most probably this is an issue with certificate formatting, may be missing escape character at the end of each line in certificate etc.

You can try using the Certificate fingerprint instead to see if it works.